# Using a custom struct as a type in another struct in Go not building

Tags: go

I have the following dir structure:

```
github.com
    meee
      projectA
        foo
         foo.go
        bar
         bar.go
```

In foo.go:

```
package foo

import(
  "github.com/meee/projectA/bar"
)
type Foo struct {
  Name string
  Bars []Bar
}
```

In bar.go:

```
package bar

type Bar struct {
  Name string
}
```

This will not compile/build, the error I get is:

```
undefined: Bar
```

Since I have it imported, I do not know why it will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import `fmt`, you cannot call `Println` directly. You must call `fmt.Println` instead; otherwise, you get the `undefined: Println` error.

It's the same for your `bar` package. This should work now:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
    Bars []bar.Bar
}
```